# iOS: Frame and picture autolayout

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Say I have two UIViews. One is a UIImageView of a frame, and one is a UIImageView of a picture. I want the picture to stay inside the frame regardless of screen size using autolayout. The picture is NOT a subview of the frame - they're just two imageviews that I want to remain superimposed in the right proportions.

I can't pin the heights, because I want them to change when rotating (for arguments sake say I pinned the frames bottom to the bottom of the main view). I can't make the heights equal, because they're not, the picture should be smaller. I can pin the horizontal spacing, but that will just make sure the picture's x,y are right, but not height and width.

I want it so that if for whatever reason I change the frames size (via transform, for example), the picture will follow.

Can I do this in autolayout, or is coding required?

Comment: Why would you use a transform and not make the pic a subview?

Answer (score 0):

You can make constraints pinning the centerX and centerY of the two views to be the same. Then you can make constraints to specify the width and the height. It depends on how big your frame is. You might try

```
picture.width = frame.width - 20
```

or

```
picture.width = 0.8 * frame.width
```

(and do something similar for the height).

If you want them both to rotate, you need to either set the rotation transform on both views (not recommended) or put them both in the same superview and set the rotation transform on that superview (recommended). Remember, if a view has a transform set then you can't make a constraint that goes from within that view to something outside that view. They are like separate worlds.